# Timed Notification after Push Button -- Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, notifications

So I am creating a companion app for a game. Let's just say it won't be integrated into the game for now so it is in its own app. How can i push a button and 5 minutes later get a push notification for it? If its a dupe question, please give me the other question. In android studio 3.0.1. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. Hope this helps

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent resultIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mNotificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle("TEST")
                .setContentText("HELLO WORLD!")
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentIntent(resultIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(0, mNotificationBuilder.build());
  }
}, 50000); //5 mins
```